# I have written a code for converting decimal number to binary number which is not giving desired output

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

```
//program to give binary equivalent of a decimal number without using recurssion
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
  int i=0,num,bin=0;
  printf("enter number : ");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  while(num>0)
  {
      bin+=((float)(num%2))*pow(10.0,(float)i++);
      num/=2;
  }
  printf("Binary equivalent is : %d",bin);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

This code dosen't provide desired output for inputs like 7, but does provide desired output for some numbers.Can you please help me out find the error.

Comment: The reason is you

Comment: What output you get for 7 ?

Comment: binary equivalent of 7 is 111, but the code is giving 110

Comment: If you use float instead of integer, any cast back to the integer can be a problem. You shouldn't use floating point in your algorithm.

Comment: Hmm. Here I get 111. Maybe a bug in your fp arithmetic. Which architecture/compiler do you use?

Comment: Yes, but % operator dosen't work with float.

Comment: I use windows 10(64-bit), gcc compiler.

Comment: @aj14 see the duplicate target. `(int)pow(10, 2)` results in 99. 99 + 10 + 1 = 110; but yeah, this is not even a [mcve] as it doesn't state a) the actual result, b) the expected result, c) how to reproduce (i.e. using this GCC version here...).

Comment: @aj14: using bin as a float, and print it as %f , then you would see.

Comment: found alternative, i=1 in initialisation, and in loop bin+=(num%2)*i;i*=10;num/=2;

Comment: @aj14: you're absolutely right, avoid casts from floating point to integer, and use integer `i*=10`. You should answer your question by yourself.

Comment: You are converting a decimal number to binary with `scanf("%d",&num)`, and the remaining code converts. or is supposed to convert, a binary number to something else. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: bin = 0; factor = 1; do { bin += factor * (num & 1); num >>= 1; factor *= 10; } while (num > 0);